# JiBX trim-whitespace ambiguiti

Tags: java, whitespace, trim, jibx

I was trying to add a trimming feature to my JiBX bindings. From what the documentation said I can either add custom converters and then add  in the bindings OR I can add a trim-whitespaces="true" attribute to the  node.

Now it works, but not in every case. BigDecimals and booleans get trimmed, but Strings don't. So I was wondering, what does JiBX take into account when it tries to trim values with the trim-whitespace attribute on? Is it the XSD, is it the type from the java class? Can't really find in the documentation why Strings aren't trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `String.trim()` explicitly on the strings?

Comment: I could but thats not the problem. The funny thing is that I actually WANT it to trim everything but Strings (and some enums) and that it is working fine for me. I just didn't have the chance to test the whole application and I don't know whether I should look for some "bugs" or does it simply trim everything but Strings.